# postgres: how to save id's within recursion?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, recursion

I am a newby when it comes to somewhat complexer sql queries so please bear with me.

I have a street network. My final goal is update segments of "class" 5 that are touching each other by the class value of the next segment that belongs to a different class than 5.

Imagine: there are 12 segments. One 'situation' (read highway exit situation) is made of 6 segments. The first segment is a highway segment, it has class '2'. The following 4 segments are exit segments, they have the class '5'. The last segment is a local road, it has class '4'. All exit segments need to be updated to class '2'. The second situation looks similar.

I managed to identify all transition segments by running this query:

```
CREATE TABLE touch AS
SELECT s2.geom, s2.linkid, s2.class, s1.linkid AS linkid_sr FROM   
sr_buffer as s1, sr_buffer as s2
WHERE s1.class = 5 AND s2.class != 5 AND ST_EndPoint(s2.geom)=ST_StartPoint(s1.geom)
```

However, I need to identify all segments that lay in-between the transition segments. I came up with this recursive query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE walk_network(linkid, class, geom, path) AS (
    SELECT linkid, class, geom, ARRAY[linkid] FROM test_exit WHERE class = 5
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n.linkid, n.class, n.geom, path || n.linkid
    FROM test_exit n, walk_network w
    WHERE ST_EndPoint(w.geom)=ST_StartPoint(n.geom) AND n.class = 5
)

SELECT *
FROM walk_network
```

My idea was to store all linkid's that belong to one 'cluster' into an array. But the query just returns the array with the current linked instead of adding them up. I don't really understand why?

I want to find out which exit segments belong together, so adding up means either putting them into an array or table. So I can use them afterwards to look up the highest class they are attached two.

```
3882600054  7   {3882600054}
3882600056  7   {3882600056}
3882600040  7   {3882600040}
```

How can I store all linkid's for **one** recursive loop in an array? What is the best way to loop through the array afterwards to look up the values in the other table?

Or is there a way better to do this anyway?

Comment: Should work just fine. Can you setup a SQLFiddle example? (Btw: you should stop using the outdated implicit joins in the where clause and start using a proper `JOIN` operator)

Comment: As I said, I'm a newbie...

Comment: What exactly is the problem, avoiding loops in the graph (and infinite recursion ...) ?

Comment: Problem is: I want to add up all id's belonging to one 'situation'. The array just adds up the current id, not all id's of the current cycle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I guess because of the geometry part I can't put my data into SQLFiddle...

Comment: `add up ids` makes no sense to me. Do you mean: putting them into a table or array? I don't understand 'situation' and 'current cycle' either.

Comment: Imagine: there are 12 segments. One 'situation' (read highway exit situation) is made of 6 segments. The first segment is a highway segment, it has class '2'. The following 4 segments are exit segments, they have the class '5'. The last segment is a local road, it has class '4'. All exit segments need to updated to class '2'. The second situation looks similar. I want to find out which exit segments belong together, so adding up means either putting them into an array or table, yes. So I can use them afterwards to look up the highest class they are attached two.

Comment: So basically you want to simplify `{5,5,5,5} -> { 4,4,4,4}, {3,3} -> {2,2,2,2,2,2,2} --> {1,1,1,1}` into `5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 ->1} wich all the consecutive same-class segments concatenated? BTW: please add the above description to the question.

Comment: Finally the described situation should look like this (class wise) `2->2->2->2->2->4`. But for the time being I'd be happy knowing the id's of the exit segments belonging to this situation.